# Paperclip with base64 : undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<String:0xb46dba14>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, paperclip

Please help me... I use paperclip to upload 1 picture in the canvas tag (base64) to aws-s3.

**My Controller**

```
    def create
    decoded_file = Base64.decode64(params[:photo])
      begin
        file = Tempfile.new(['test', '.jpg']) 
        file.binmode
        file.write decoded_file
        file.close
        @photo.photo =  file
        if @photo.save
          render :json => {:message => "Successfully uploaded the profile picture."}
        else
          render :json => {:message => "Failed to upload image"}
        end
      ensure
        file.unlink
      end
  end
```

**Model**

```
 class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, styles: { thumbnail: "150x200#"}, default_style: :thumbnail
end
```

**And errors :**

```
NoMethodError at /photos
===================================
> undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<String:0xb46dba14>
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb, line 17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I got something.

There are 2 potential problems:

1. Your creation of a file (with canvas) might be incorrect
2. Your `@post.save` function might be incorrect

---

I don't know about the canvas stuff.... so I'm going to give you my best shot with the `@post.save`:

```
 def create
    decoded_file = Base64.decode64(params[:photo])
      begin
        file = Tempfile.new(['test', '.jpg']) 
        file.binmode
        file.write decoded_file
        file.close

        params[:photo] = file

        @photo.new(photo_params)
        if @photo.save
          render :json => {:message => "Successfully uploaded the profile picture."}
        else
          render :json => {:message => "Failed to upload image"}
        end
      ensure
        file.unlink
      end
  end

  private
  def photo_params
      params.permit(:photo)
  end
```

Comment: Now, work good. But i'm remove row "file.close". Thanks you very much.

Comment: I'm so sorry because i'm not vote for u. Because vote up requires 15 rep. :D

Comment: hehe I just upvoted your Q, now you just need another vote from where!! :)

Comment: btw if it worked, you can select the tick on the answer to make it the accepted one - this will be enough to have others upvote too I think

Answer (score 1):

are u using the update_attributes() or build() in this way ?

> update_attribures(params[:photo])

You if so you should use this instead :

> update_attributes(:photo => params[:photo])

hope that helps and works for you.

Comment: Thanks for help. But i'm not using update_attributes() or build() in this way. Any other way?